# ionicframework setting up international-phone-number directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Am learning ionic and I want to use this directive [international-phone-number direcrive](https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number). I have linked the file on my `index.html` page

```
<script src="lib/international-phone-number/releases/international-phone-number.js"></script>
```

and in my view used one of the default examples from the link `<input type="text" international-phone-number only-countries="pl, de, en, es" default-country="pl" preferred-countries="pl, de" ng-model="phone">`

the directive is not working for me , what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: did you added `intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js` in your page & `internationalPhoneNumber` module in your app module

Comment: @pankajparkar I have not added `utils.js` let me do it . an this is my app module hope its correct `angular.module("Test", ["ionic", "uiGmapgoogle-maps", "internationalPhoneNumber"])`

Comment: looks correct to me..what is the result?

Comment: @pankajparkar am getting this error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- internationalPhoneNumberDirective`

Comment: could you share you javascript file code?

Comment: @pankajparkar and this file `intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js` does't exitst either

Comment: you need to download this file , add it in your project then refer in your html file by giving path..

Comment: @pankajparkar am sending the link

Comment: @pankajparkar here is the link [code] (http://plnkr.co/edit/OCeLMLCPwdcTvDo9YQry?p=catalogue)

Comment: please add js file correctly from cdn

Comment: @pankajparkar try setting up that directive on a new angular project and see if it works . my project is basically empty